# Discord.py: Info command, How to mention roles of a member?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a info command for my Discord.py bot. It also shows the roles a user has. But it does not shows the roles properly.

[This is how it looks on Discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL8l3.png)

How do I make it so it mentioned the roles, like with other bots.

This is my code:

```
async def info(ctx, member: discord.Member):

    info_embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green())
    info_embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url_as(format=None, static_format='webp', size=1024)}")
    info_embed.add_field(name="Member:", value=f"{member.mention}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Member name", value=f"{member}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Member id:", value=f"{member.id}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Nickname:", value=f"{member.nick}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Joined at:", value=f"{member.joined_at}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Roles:", value=f"{member.roles}", inline=False)
    info_embed.set_footer(text="GG-GamerPub | auto-mod")

    await ctx.send(embed=info_embed)
```

I have tried changing it to:
`member.roles.mention` but this didn't work. It gave me the following error

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mention'
```

How can I make it so it does work? Thanks in advance

Comment: That is a list of course. Actually the user might have one or more roles and thus that is in the list. You need to iterate through the list and find the special role you want to ping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just work on that.
You can't really mention the whole list.

For Example, I have three roles: "Role 1" , "Role 2", "Role 3"

When I use `member.roles` is would give me that you saw in your embed.

But we can just fix this by using a `for` loop and iterating through the role list and mentioning then one by on.

So in your embed you need to join it to the field of `Roles:`
I would do this:

```
roles = " ".join([role.mention for role in member.roles])
info_embed.add_field(name="Roles:", value=f"{roles}", inline=False)
```

This would return something like this:

[image: 1]

Adding it to your code:

```
async def info(ctx, member: discord.Member):

    info_embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green())
    info_embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url_as(format=None, static_format='webp', size=1024)}")
    info_embed.add_field(name="Member:", value=f"{member.mention}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Member name", value=f"{member}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Member id:", value=f"{member.id}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Nickname:", value=f"{member.nick}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Joined at:", value=f"{member.joined_at}", inline=False)
    roles = " ".join([role.mention for role in member.roles if role.name != "@everyone"])
    info_embed.add_field(name="Roles:", value=f"{roles}", inline=False)
    info_embed.set_footer(text="GG-GamerPub | auto-mod")

    await ctx.send(embed=info_embed)
```

---

I wanted to add one improvised feature so I did that. If there is no user mentioned then the member is the user who executed the command.

```
async def info(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member:
        info_user = member
    elif member == None:
        info_user = ctx.author
    info_embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green())
    info_embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{info_user.avatar_url_as(format=None, static_format='webp', size=1024)}")
    info_embed.add_field(name="Member:", value=f"{info_user.mention}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Member name", value=f"{info_user}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Member id:", value=f"{info_user.id}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Nickname:", value=f"{info_user.nick}", inline=False)
    info_embed.add_field(name="Joined at:", value=f"{info_user.joined_at}", inline=False)
    roles = " ".join([role.mention for role in info_user.roles if role.name != "@everyone"])
    info_embed.add_field(name="Roles:", value=f"{roles}", inline=False)
    info_embed.set_footer(text="GG-GamerPub | auto-mod")

    await ctx.send(embed=info_embed)
```

---

I hope you understand and if you still have any doubt, please ask me in the comment.

Thank You! :D

Comment: This also worked, all of it! Thanks for the help

Comment: @KipZonderKop101 Aww c'mon! I was he one more elaborate in my answer! (-_-)

Comment: changed it @Bhavyadeep Yadav

Comment: No need to put f"{roles}" in an fstring, it's already a string

Comment: @RedstoneRadiant Alright mate

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are trying to use `mention` atrribute on `roles` not `role`. You can use [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) and [`join()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) to do get mentions of roles:

```
f"{' '.join([role.mention for role in member.roles])}"
```

It will return `role.mention`s seperated by spaces. If you want to exclude @everyone you can use if statement inside of list comprehension. Like this:

```
f"{' '.join([role.mention for role in member.roles if role.name != '@everyone'])}"
```

Comment: Can you please mentioned they should do this? I mean yes it is obvious but many other people can come looking or this!